# this VHDL code for a 64-bit timer?

Tags: memory-optimization, vhdl

I have code for a 64-bit timer register which can take in a 32-bit slice and depending on the inputs, place the slice in the high side or the low side, or increment the counter.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity CSR_TIMER is
    Port ( clk : in STD_LOGIC;
           reset: in STD_LOGIC := '0';
           DATA_IN : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           EN_WRITE_LOW : in STD_LOGIC;
           EN_WRITE_HIGH : in STD_LOGIC;
           DATA_LOW_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           DATA_HIGH_OUT : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end CSR_TIMER;

architecture Behavioral of CSR_TIMER is
    signal clock,clock_next : unsigned(63 downto 0) := x"0000000000000000";
begin
    clock_next <=
    x"0000000000000000"                     when (reset = '1') else
    clock(63 downto 32) & unsigned(DATA_IN) when (EN_WRITE_LOW = '1') else
    unsigned(DATA_IN) & clock(31 downto 0)  when (EN_WRITE_HIGH = '1') else
    clock+1;
    
    DATA_LOW_OUT <=
    std_logic_vector(clock(31 downto 0));
    
    DATA_HIGH_OUT <=
    std_logic_vector(clock(63 downto 32));

    process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            clock<=clock_next;
        end if;
    end process;

end Behavioral;
```

The trouble that I'm having is that the timer takes up too many physical resources, and I'm looking to shrink it down. This is for a RISC-V Processor where the ISA specifies that a proper processor has 32 of these timers, which is 2kb of on-board memory, and is not friendly to any FPGA. The Data_Low_out and data_high_out are connected to a mux, where they are treated as separate registers at different addresses.

How can I optimize this timer ( or a group of 32 timers ) to reduce the physical resource usage? This is synthesized using Vivado 2020.1.

Comment: Hi, please [edit] the title of this question so that it **only states the purpose of your code**, anything else belongs to the body